# Will Increased amount of Amps affect dc motors

Tags: current, current-limiting

I've a 12 volt 1 Amp rated adapter and would like to hook up 2 12 volt 0.18 Amps Dc motor in parallel circuit to power them up, would the over rated amps effect my dc motors and if so how can i reduce Amps without reducing its volts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use another example: I have a 100 W motor that I'm going to plug into the Irish national grid which has a capacity of 5 GW at peak capacity. Do you think it will burn out my motor?

Answer: No. The motor will draw the current it requires. This current is limited by the resistance of the motor.

Back to your question:

> Would the over rated amps effect my DC motors and if so how can I reduce amps without reducing its volts?

The motor will draw the current it requires.

Comment: Since the OP was asking about current this answer would be better if you used amps rather than watts.

Answer (score 0):

2 * 0.18 is less than 1 amp so it will be fine. The extra capacity from the adaptor will not be a problem.

Comment: What if the same goes for series circuit, would there be any change than..?